# Customize interface for Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to change the user interface for Visual Studio Code? Specifically, is it possible to remove the "Git" and "Debugger" panes? Also, how can you edit the menus in the main menu bar?

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the menu in VSCode. The menu items are fix. 
For now (speaking for version 1.2.1) you can change the color theme only to customize the user interface.